# Simplify $\tan(360 - \theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am aware that $\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\dfrac{\tan(\alpha)-\tan(\beta)}{1+\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}$

So for my question:

$\tan(360 - \theta)$

Do I choose random value for $\theta$ and plug it into the formula? How do I use this piece of information?

Comment: Taking into account your previous post, I think you really need to read again some basic properties in trigonometry. Do it, it is not difficult.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The answer is already in your question.

Comment: Pretty simple! I can see the solution directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\dfrac{\tan(\alpha)-\tan(\beta)}{1+\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}$ 
with $\alpha = 360$

if you really want to use the formula above, then do it like this:

$\tan(360^{\circ}) = \tan(0^{\circ}) = 0$

that means 
$\tan(\alpha-\beta)=\dfrac{0-\tan(\beta)}{1 + 0*\tan(\beta)} = -\tan(\beta)$

Comment: How is tan(360degrees) = tan(0degrees) ?

Comment: Just imagine a unit circle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle If you go 360° you are back to 0°, so tan(360°) is the same as tan(0°)

Answer (score 3):

Why making thinks hard? $\cos(360°-\theta )=\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(360°-\theta )=\sin(-\theta )=-\sin(\theta)$ ($360°=2\pi$).It's a known rule.

So $\tan(360°-\theta)=\dfrac{\sin(360°-\theta )}{\cos(360°-\theta )}=-\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}=-\tan(\theta)$

If you really want to use the formula you gave, take $(\alpha ,\beta)=(360°,\theta)$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\tan (360-\theta) = \frac{\sin(360- \theta )}{\cos(360- \theta )}
$$
and since $\sin(\theta)$ is an odd function and $\cos(\theta)$ is an even function,

$$
\frac{\sin(360-\theta )}{\cos(360-\theta )}=\frac{-\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}=-\tan(\theta)
$$

You could use the double angle formula for $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ to justify further the second step.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan(360^{\circ}-\theta)=\tan(-\theta+360^{\circ})=\tan(-\theta+2\cdot180^{\circ})=\tan(-\theta)=-\tan(\theta)$$
since $\tan x$ is perodic and odd